# Click event on Dropdown items - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire click event when selecting elements from drop down list items. each click event should be diiferent depend on the value of element in drop down.

```
 <select id="cmbMoreFunction" name="cmbMoreFunction" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="0">ATM Event Status</option>
            <option value="1">Statistics</option>
 </select>
```

If I Click on "ATM Event Status" Only its specific click event should get fired.

I tried this ..but doesnt work

```
 $('#cmbMoreFunction select option').click(function() 
 { 
    //Depend on Value i.e. 0 or 1 respective function gets called. 
 });
```

Basically I just dont want another BUTTON on my page for catch all the value and then fire event.

Comment: Why not use one change handler for all items, and in the handler read the option value and decide what to do there?

Comment: Sure, I'll put it in an answer

Comment: $('#cmbMoreFunction option').click(function()
 { 
    var value = $(this).text();
    alert(value);
 });​

Comment: if you add a blank space between *#cmbMoreFunction* and *select*, it means find sub-tags *select* in $('#cmbMoreFunction'). But in your case *select* and *#cmbMoreFunction* is the same tag. So you may write like $('select#cmbMoreFunction'), even though there is no need to do that. In your case, use $('#cmbMoreFunction option') to select items.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the change handler on the select, read it's value, and decide what to do then:

```
$('#cmbMoreFunction').change(function() 
{ 
    var selectedValue = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());

    //Depend on Value i.e. 0 or 1 respective function gets called. 
    switch(selectedValue){
        case 0:
            handlerFunctionA();
            break;
        case 1:
            handlerFunctionB();
            break;
        //etc... 
        default:
            alert("catch default");
            break;
    }
});

function handlerFunctionA(){
    alert("do some stuff");    
}

function handlerFunctionB(){
    alert("Do some other stuff");
}
```

​

[Here is a working fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sfGug/2/)

Comment: change the first line of your script to $('#cmbMoreFunction').change(function() {

Comment: Your selector is wrong, you need to select the entire select element, by using it's ID. Now You are trying to select a select element inside your select element, which will not work obviously :)

Comment: Yup Its working now. i put alert to display val of "selectedValue" BUT in Case 0 i wrote -> window.open("ATMStatus.aspx", "ATM Event Mapper"); Nothing happens ...Why ??

Comment: Because the switch statement checks for int values. You need to parse the value of the selectbox to an int too. See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QBcW4/4/

Comment: Besides, does not need `break` for `default` statement.

Answer (score 5):

check this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrETs/)

Simple use this code
**JQuery:**

```
$('#cmbMoreFunction').click(function(v){
  console.log(v.target.value);
  });
```

Hopefully your problem will solved.

Answer (score 2):

A option element will not have a click event. Click event is associated with Select element only so you will have to apply it to select dropdown. In the function that fires on click event of select dropdown, you can then check individual options and apply your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use javascript. eg.

```
$document.ready(function(){
$('#cmbMoreFunction').change(function(){

var dataValue=document.getElementById('cmbMoreFunction').value;
if(dataValue==0){call functionFirst();}
else{call functionSecond();}
});
});
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer (how it solves solves the original question) with your code? ... for others who visit this question in the future?